# field 'license' doesn't exist on type 'Repository' error in Ballerina github4 api

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to retrieve an owner repository and get it's number of forks. But when I run the specific file, I get the following error:

> error: wso2/github4:0.9.10:GitClientError, message: field 'license'
>   doesn't exist on type 'Repository'

shown below is my code:

```
import ballerina/config;  
import ballerina/http;

import ballerina/io;

import wso2/github4;  
import wso2/sonarqube6;

 function main(string... args) {

     json summary = check getLineCoverageSummary();
     io:println(summary); }

 function getLineCoverageSummary() returns json|error {

     endpoint github4:Client githubEP {
         clientConfig: {
             auth: {
                 scheme: http:OAUTH2,
                 accessToken: config:getAsString("GITHUB_TOKEN")
             }
         }
     };

     json summaryJson;
         github4:Repository repository;
     var repo = githubEP->getRepository("suleka96/backend-routes-temp");
     match repo {
         github4:Repository reposi => {
             repository = reposi;
             summaryJson = repository.forkCount;
         }
         github4:GitClientError err => {
             return err;
         }
     }  


     return summaryJson; 
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed now and the updated GitHub connector is pushed to Ballerina Central with the version of 0.9.13.

https://central.ballerina.io/wso2/github4

Pull the updated connector and try it again!

`ballerina pull wso2/github4`